# AsyncTask to display Response form WCF

Tags: java, c#, android, wcf, android-asynctask

I wrote a Restful WCF service and it is deployed on IIS. I have been attempting to consume the WCF Service using a `AsyncTask` Thread. I built the thread in to the main UI class so that I can update the GUI.

```
public class ServiceRunning extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    private Exception exception;
    String line = "";

    public void setLine(String line)
    {
        this.line = line;
    }
    public String getLine()
    {
        return line;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        try 
        {

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                URI uri = new URI(url[0]); 

                HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
                httpget.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                httpget.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);
                HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
               // while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                 //   Log.d("****Status Line***", "Webservice: " + line);

             // }
                while((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    setLine(line);
                    Log.d("****Status Line***", "Webservices: " + getLine());

                }


        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "String :" + line;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txt.setText(getLine());
    }


}
```

In the code, I write the response to a String and I attempt to display it after execution. For some resound, when I run the program I don't get the response, I get a blank TextView but the message displays in the Eclipse `LogCat`. I cant find the problem, what causes this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AsyncTask is tied to the activity kicking it off. If you rotate the device or the app goes into the background, is added or removed from a dock, the original activity is destroyed. The AsyncTask continues though and responds to the original activity that is no longer visible.

You are better off using an IntentService or Service to call web services, it is a much more reliable pattern.

Comment: Well when the application received the response the response was written to the LOGCAT and nullified after that. So I removed the writing to the LOGCAT and it works now. Thanks for your help anyway